# Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my code:

```
function App() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState();
  const [imageURL, setImage] = useState();
  const [box, setBox] = useState({});
  

  const calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById('inputImage');
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    console.log(width, height);
    console.log(clarifaiFace);
  };

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  const onButtonSubmit = () => {
    setImage(input);
    console.log(input);
    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      "user_app_id": {
          "user_id": USER_ID,
          "app_id": APP_ID
      },
      "inputs": [
          {
              "data": {
                  "image": {
                      "url": input
                  }
              }
          }
      ]
  });

  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Key ' + PAT
      },
      body: raw
  };

    fetch("https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" + MODEL_ID + "/outputs", requestOptions)
        // .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => calculateFaceLocation(response.json()))
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  
  };
```

I'm getting the error when I try to console.log(clarifaiFace). The console returns the message "error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at calculateFaceLocation (App.js:25:1)"

I tried console.log(data) to see if the object was not being passed to the calculateFaceLocation function, but it seems like it worked, as seen in the image.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDNQM.png)
So, the issue is that somehow I can't access the index in the object. Already tried a bunch of things but didn't work. Really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible issue with your code: outputs could be undefined because the json method returns a Promise, not the content directly (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json). You can chain a then() after the .json() to collect the "real" json content and give it to calculateFaceLocation.

```js
fetch(url, options)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => calculateFaceLocation(data))
```